# How to add required error message to my input in Zend Framework 1.11?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element, zend-validate

I have the following code snippets in my forms/video.php. But i do not know where to add the validation message for required.

```
$this->addElement('text','name', array(
        'label'=>'Name',
        'maxlength'=>20,
        'class'=>'name',
        'required'=>true,
        'filters'=>array('StringTrim'),
        'decorators'=>array(
            'ViewHelper',
            'Errors',
            array(array('control'=>'HtmlTag'), array('tag'=>'div', 'class'=>'fieldcontrol')),
            array('Label', array('tag'=>'div', 'class'=>'name')),
            array(array('row'=>'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div', 'class'=>'row')),
        )
    ));
```

Instead of "Value is required and can't be empty", I would like to set it to something else like "Please enter your name".

Comment: There's a very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/459921/zend-form-nicely-change-setrequired-validate-message . You should find some interesting answers there.

Comment: I understand that it's similar, but in my case, i am adding the entire element, with validation, as arguments into $this->addElement. Is it not possible using the addElement approach? Sorry, as i am new to ZF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the end, i got this to work:

```
$this->addElement('text', 'age', array(
            'label'=>'Age',
            'maxlength'=>2,
            'class'=>'age',
            'required'=>true,
            'filters'=>array('StringTrim'),
            'validators'=>array(
                array(
                    'validator'=>'NotEmpty',
                    'options'=>array(
                        'messages'=>'Please enter your age.'
                    ),
                    'breakChainOnFailure'=>true
                ),
                array(
                    'validator'=>'Int',
                    'options'=>array(
                        'messages'=>'Age must be a number.'
                    ),
                    'breakChainOnFailure'=>true
                ),
                array(
                    'validator'=>'between',
                    'options'=>array(
                        'min'=>8,
                        'max'=>10,
                        'messages'=>array(
                            Zend_Validate_Between::NOT_BETWEEN => 'This is for %min% to %max% years old.'
                        )
                    )
                ),

            ),
            'decorators'=>array(
                'ViewHelper',
                'Errors',
                array(array('control'=>'HtmlTag'), array('tag'=>'div', 'class'=>'fieldcontrol')),
                array('Label', array('tag'=>'div', 'class'=>'age')),
                array(array('row'=>'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div', 'class'=>'row')),
            ),
        ));
```

Comment: For ZF2.2, the specification should be like this:
`array('name'=>'NotEmpty', 'options'=>array('messages'=>'Please enter your age.'), 'break_chain_on_failure'=>true)`

Comment: @herophuong It's not for ZF2 but ok

Answer (score 1):

I would likely leave the `required` set to default and use the `NotEmpty` validator instead.

```
$this->addElement('text', 'age', array(
            'label'=>'Age',
            'maxlength'=>2,
            'class'=>'age',
            'filters'=>array('StringTrim'),
            'validators'=>array(
                array(
                    'validator'=>'Int',
                    'options'=>array(
                        'messages'=>'Age must be a number.'
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    'validator'=>'NotEmpty',
                    'options'=>array(
                        'messages'=>'Please enter your age.'
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    'validator'=>'between',
                    'options'=>array(
                        'min'=>8,
                        'max'=>10,
                        'messages'=>array(
                            Zend_Validate_Between::NOT_BETWEEN => 'Your age must be between %min% to %max%.'
                        )
                    )
                )
            ),
            'decorators'=>array(
                'ViewHelper',
                'Errors',
                array(array('control'=>'HtmlTag'), array('tag'=>'div', 'class'=>'fieldcontrol')),
                array('Label', array('tag'=>'div', 'class'=>'age')),
                array(array('row'=>'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div', 'class'=>'row')),
            ),
        ));
```

`NotEmpty()` does essentially the same thing as `isRequired()` but is an actual validator where `isRequired()` is just a flag set in `Zend_Form_Element`. Also it should'nt mess up your messages.

Answer (score 0):

**Editted**

This should do it:

```
...
$name = $this->getElement('name')->addErrorMessage('Please enter your name');
...
```

Comment: If you are refering to $this->addElement(...)->addErrorMessage('Error message'), that wont work as $this->addElement return the form itself and not the element.